# Names of all page columns

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

How can I use ClosedXML to get a list of all the used columns in an excel table? This is how columns are issued for all cells. I didn't find a suitable method only for columns

```
var cells = source_sheet.CellsUsed();
foreach (var c in cells)
{}
```

Pulled out the used speakers like this. But it looks like something... not really =)

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
var cells = sheet.CellsUsed();
foreach(var c in cells)
{
    if (names.Contains(c.Address.ColumnLetter))
        break;
    else
        names.Add(c.Address.ColumnLetter);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In ClosedXML, is there anyway to get the column letter from column header name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574790/in-closedxml-is-there-anyway-to-get-the-column-letter-from-column-header-name)

Comment: @Mikael, a specific column is searched for here. I need to get all the headlines

Answer (score 0):

If your data is really in a defined Excel *table* , then you can return the field names as follows:

```
using var wb = new XLWorkbook("test.xlsx");
var ws = wb.Worksheets.First();

var table = ws.Tables.First();
var names = table.Fields.Select(f => f.Name).ToList();

foreach (var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
```

If your data is just in regular cells, you can do:

```
using var wb = new XLWorkbook("test.xlsx");
var ws = wb.Worksheets.First();

var names = ws.ColumnsUsed().Select(c => c.Cell(rowNumber: 1).GetString()).ToList();

foreach (var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
```